# .htaccess удаление поддомена

Tags: url, .htaccess, wordpress

Каким образом изменить URL через htaccess, дабы избавиться от поддомена

`subdomain.domain.com/page` привести к виду `domain.com/page`

Comment: @quoter, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

На `subdomain.domain.com` разместить .htaccess с редиректом типа

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R, L]
```

**Обновление**

Как удобно. Посмотри логи RewriteLog, в них указано в чем проблема или обратись к админам сервера. Еще можно попробовать так:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

Возможно у тебя просто отсутствует `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: такое делал, оно да работает, но только для главной, подстраницы отдают 500 ошибку

Comment: 500 ошибку выдает domain.com или subdomain?

Comment: domain.com

Comment: Добавь RewriteEngine on перед RewriteRule

Comment: есть оно, и Options +FollowSymLinks пробовал и много всякого, чейто не пошло

Забил, сделал не поддоменом, а дирректорией, и просто повырезал ее,

Comment: Обновил ответ